# How to run ifelse in R for multiple values from a list and to set condition boundary between those in list vs those in not?

Tags: r, list, if-statement

I have a script that looks like this

```
df$Col1<-ifelse(df$race == STOP_AUDIT[RACE],
                         "Yes", "No")
```

I have a list called RACE

```
RACE<-c("WHITE","BLACK","HISPANIC","ASIAN")
```

This is the outcome i want for my dataset.

```
           race|Col1
 BLACK          Yes
 ASIAN          Yes
 WHITE          Yes
 WHITE HISPANIC No
 HISPANIC       Yes
 ASIAN          Yes
 BLACK HISPANIC No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to check when an item is in another vector. This is vectorised, as in:

```r
df$Col1<-ifelse(df$race %in% RACE, "Yes", "No")
```